# Response processing with ASP.NET functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a function in the c# code behind that fires on a button click.  This should change a span to "DONE", and then if the ZipFile checkbox is checked, fire off a zip file to the user.

```
    Process.Text = "DONE";
    if (ZipFile.Checked)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + folderName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddDirectory(Server.MapPath("PDFs")+"/"+folderName);
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.End();
    }
```

If the checkbox is unchecked, DONE is displayed.  If the ZipFile checkbox is checked, it will send the zip file, but will no longer change the process.text = DONE.  The response seems to be overwriting the ASP.NET function return.  But as this is my first time using Response, I am clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing it's `Response.End` that's your problem.

Comment: @RickS It's not.  I added that after, to see if it would help.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do in one response.  As far as I know, the response can either be the page, or the zip file.  And you can only supply one response per request.  You'll need some client-side scripting to pull this off.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of setting text on the server side, set it on the client side. Try following snippet:

```
<script>
    function btnProcessClicked() {
        $('#<%= Process.ClientID %>').text("DONE");
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

However, in this approach, remember that if you don't set the text on server side as well then in the scenario (!ZipFile.Checked), the span will revert back to the last server value after the postback.

Comment: The whole issue is that I can't just have it say done right when the button is pressed.  The whole point of the DONE message is that it might not display for 30+ seconds, ie, whenever the server code is done.  My code is reading from a large text area, and generating PDFs.  This could take a while.  The done message shouldn't display until this long server side process is finished.  (I am assuming the code you posted is a on the HTML/client side using JS).